# AngularJS How to decode a jsonp response with a token and user infomation inside?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my angularJS app, I get the following response after a jsonp http request.

```
angular.callbacks._1({
  "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2IjowLCJpYXQiOjE0NjAxMDQ3MzIsImQiOnsidWl...",
    "user":{
    "uid":"lda...",
    "sn":"Hugo",
    "mail":"abc@bla.com",
    "mobile":""
    }})
```

When I make a json parser of this response.

```
JSON.parse(response)
```

The error of "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" appears. Can someone help me to decode this json string ?

```
angular.js:13283 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/satellizer/satellizer.js:518:34
    at processQueue (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15616:28)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15632:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16884:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16700:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16992:24)
    at done (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11313:47)
    at completeRequest (http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11511:7)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11421:9
```

Comment: You need parse this JSON in your angular code? Can you show how you do request?

Comment: Can you post the code where you decode the json ? Also when does the error appears exactly ?

Comment: I added the error info

Comment: Its valid JSON according to JSONLint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSONP is returning a JavaScript object, not a JavaScript string containing JSON. (Despite its name, JSONP is not JSON. It is JavaScript.)

It gets parsed by the JavaScript parser.

When you call `JSON.parse(response)` you are implicitly calling `JSON.parse(response.toString())`, which is giving you `JSON.parse("[object Object]")`

Just use `response` directly, don't try to treat it as JSON.

```
var token = response.data.token;
var user = response.data.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in AngularJS

```
                        var token = response.data['token']
                        var user = response.data['user']
```